# Django retrieve key of group ChoiceField

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

retrieve key of group ChoiceField

```
MEDIA_CHOICES = (
('Audio', (
        ('vinyl', 'Vinyl'),
        ('cd', 'CD'),
    )
),
('Video', (
        ('vhs', 'VHS Tape'),
        ('dvd', 'DVD'),
    )
),
('unknown', 'Unknown'),
```

)

```
class ressource(models.Model):
....

media = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=MEDIA_CHOICES)
```

in field media i have vinyl or cd or vhs or dvd...but how retrieve audio,video, unknown ?

Comment: What you mean retrieve ? You want to get(SELECT) data from database ?

Comment: i want for example a report : in our ressource we have 4 audio (3 cd, 1 vinyl) 15 video (12 vhs, 3dvd) and 10 unknowwn

Answer (score 0):

You should prove us more details. First of all choices should be `iterable` object (`tuple` for example as it's in your case), but your `tuple` is very complicated in your case (Django can not process this). You should pass something like this as a choices.

## choices example (This is good tuple code)

```
CHOICES = (
    ('key', 'value') # key will be inserted in database (and validation purposes), and  value is just for representation purposes.
)
LANGUAGES = (
    ('python', 'Python'),
    ('js', 'JS'),
    ('ruby', 'Ruby'),
)
```

Imagine that, you are trying to retrieving object from database.

```
class ressource(models.Model):
    ''' This is your model '''
    media = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=MEDIA_CHOICES)

res = ressource.objects.get(pk=1) # retrieve data from database.
print(res.media) # returns string object. you will read actual value of media field
''' But if you want to read all available choices on this field, Django provide as _meta api. You can use it very nice way '''
res = ressource.objects.get(pk=1)
fields = res._meta.fields # This will return tuple-like object.
for field in fields:
    if field.name == 'media':
        # you want to find "media" field
        print(field.choices) # This will return all available choices on your media field
```

Hope, it helps you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks but i want choices by categories (vinyl & cd -> categorie Audio, vhs & dvd -> categorie video....) also i want  count ressources by categories (audio, video...)

Comment: You are welcome. `CHOICES` is not stuff which you should use in this case. You need relational database. `ForeignKey` class will be ideal in your case.